# Loopback Device Not Configured On Boot

Tags: networking, debian-squeeze

My knowledge of network interfaces on linux is limited at best, so I was hoping someone could help me figure out the best solution to a problem I have inadvertently caused.

After boot, the loopback device on my workstation doesn't appear to exist. Things requiring the loopback address (such as running JUnit test suites in Eclipse) don't work correctly. However, it used to be fine until recently, not long after I'd been fiddling around with the iptables to forward port 80 to port 8080, so it's probably something I've done, but I have no idea how to fix it, and so far all Googling hasn't turned up any pointers (I probably don't know the right search terms...)

Firstly, the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
pre-up iptables-restore /etc/iptables.conf
post-down /etc/iptables-flush-all
```

Now, after booting my machine:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:e8:25:90:5d  
          inet addr:10.33.1.106  Bcast:10.33.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:e8ff:fe25:905d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:500239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:334565 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:617321176 (588.7 MiB)  TX bytes:36019254 (34.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0x8000
```

If I run `ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1`, then every thing is fine and the output of `ifconfig` changes to:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:e8:25:90:5d  
          inet addr:10.33.1.106  Bcast:10.33.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:e8ff:fe25:905d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:606221 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:407173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:767892736 (732.3 MiB)  TX bytes:42051623 (40.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35668 (34.8 KiB)  TX bytes:35668 (34.8 KiB)
```

So, can anyone help me figure out what I've done to break my loopback address?

**Edit 0**: Contents of `/etc/iptables.conf`:

```
chris@PC:~$ sudo cat /etc/iptables.conf 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Thu Nov 10 17:01:44 2011
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:440]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:102]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:58]
-A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080 
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 10 17:01:44 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Thu Nov 10 17:01:44 2011
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4787:2521834]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4544:2507689]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4190:913164]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4117:908160]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 10 17:01:44 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Thu Nov 10 17:01:44 2011
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2699:1514101]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2525:612477]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 10 17:01:44 2011
```

chris@PC:~$ `sudo iptables -L -t filter`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

chris@PC:~$ `sudo iptables -L -t mangle`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

chris@PC:~$ `sudo iptables -L -t nat`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Edit 1**:
Commenting out the pre-up and post-down lines for `eth0` in my `/etc/network/interfaces` appears to eliminate the issue.

My loopback address was properly configured during booting after changing `/etc/network/interfaces` to this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
#pre-up iptables-restore /etc/iptables.conf
#post-down /etc/iptables-flush-all
```

These 2 lines are intended to load and unload the iptables rules when the interface is enabled and disabled. I've read that this is a better way of configuring the firewall in Debian than loading all the rules at boot time.

The contents of `/etc/iptables-flush-all` is:

chris@PC:~$ `sudo cat /etc/iptables-flush-all`

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables --flush
iptables -t nat --flush
iptables -t mangle --flush
iptables -t filter --flush
```

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/iptables.conf & iptables -L?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the iptables config following boot and the contents of my `iptables.conf` file. I have noticed from that output that it seems my config file hasn't been loaded, as the redirect isn't in place, but that'd be a problem for another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work without your firewall being loaded?

BTW, "ifconfig" is deprecated; it's best to use "ip" for everything including diagnostics. Not that I think this is related to your problem at all.

Comment: Based on my edit above, with the output of iptables -L following a boot, I don't think my iptables are being loaded correctly anyway

Comment: Commenting out the lines that are supposed to load my iptable rules in `/etc/network/interfaces` does eliminate the problem. It now seems to me that there is an issue with how I'm attempting to load my firewall rules

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was matter of proper configuring /etc/hosts.

Get your hostname with the command *hostname* and set the /etc/hosts this way:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=739251
... I've got iptables-restore in lo pre-up and it included -A INPUT -i ! lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j reject which is now deprecated syntax ...

So, if you have line like

> pre-up iptables-restore /etc/iptables.up.rules

in /etc/network/interfaces, check that the rules are ok.

In the specific case of 739251 bug, replace

> -A INPUT -i ! lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j reject

with

> -A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j reject