# No network loopback device after security update ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04, interface, loopback

I've had Ubuntu 12.04 on a server for the last several months, with everything working fine.  Last night I did an `aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade` to bring in all the latest security changes, and now when I boot the server no lo device is created.

It brings up the physical ethernet interfaces correctly, and I can ping in and out of the machine on those interfaces, but nothing can connect to anything on either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

`ifconfig` lists only `eth0` and `eth1`.

No `lo` at all.

Here are the contents of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Where should I be looking to diagnose and fix?

Thanks!

Comment: ...me too on 12.04.2. Machine boots fine, but no 'lo' shown by ifconfig. "ifup lo" brings it right up and then all is well (after stop/start of some servers that weren't happy without lo at boot.)

You ever figure this out?

Comment: Please check your /etc/hosts.

http://serverfault.com/questions/333269/loopback-device-not-configured-on-boot

Comment: @quangdog I am pretty sure this has been long resolved/forgotten but in a slight chance it has not been: what is the output of `ifconfig -a` on this machine?

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problem.

My `lo` didn't start automatically at boot (after turning off IPv6 via sysctl and rebooting the server).

My first *workaround* was to start it manually with `ifup --force lo`. But after that I had to restart most of my services as they didn't work properly without loopback.

Finally [this old forum post](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux/69533-loopback-doesnt-come-up-correctly-boot-post383508.html?s=dd78947fdea658ef15f5f4578d7fbfb7#post383508) helped me to find out the proper and permanent **solution**:

1. `sudo rm -rf /var/run/network/*`
2. `sudo reboot`

(Apparently there was some old `.lock` file there that prevented the loopback to start properly.)

Comment: Note that ifconfig is deprecated. Use `ip addr show` instead.

Comment: nice find! never would have thought to look in there.

Answer (score 0):

If lo can be brought up manually with `ifup lo` but isn't brought up automatically, you should be able to put the command `ifup lo` in `/etc/rc.local` so it will start at each boot.  Not an elegant solution but it should be a permanent solution.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Also tried with --force (which works on interactive shell) but to no avail.